# Version ranges defined in pom.xml while using features-maven-plugin not resolved properly

Tags: maven, version

I am running into problems using the features-maven-plugin with version ranges defined in my dependencies.

It works fine if I don't use version ranges.

Is this a known issue or am I doing something wrong?
  It says :

```
    -
[INFO] -- Start generating H:\WDP\workspace\com.company.ssb.pm.ilexamplebundle\target\classes\feature.xml --
[INFO]  Generating feature org.osgi.core from org.osgi:org.osgi.core:jar:4.3.1:provided
[INFO]   adding bundle org.osgi:org.osgi.core:jar:4.3.1:provided
[INFO]  Generating feature api from com.company.ssb.nbda.cpm:api:jar:0.9.1:compile
[WARNING] Unable to retrieve metadata for com.company.ssb.cpm.common:pmcore:jar:[0.1,):compile, not including dependencies for it
Downloading: http://artifacts.ijk.company.se:8081/nexus/content/groups/public/com/company/ssb/cpm/common/pmcore/[0.1,)/pmcore-[0.1,).jar

[WARNING] Unable to determine if com.company.ssb.cpm.common:pmcore:jar:[0.1,):compile is a bundle; defaulting to false
org.apache.maven.artifact.resolver.ArtifactResolutionException: Could not transfer artifact com.company.ssb.cpm.common:pmcore:jar:[0.1,) from/to artifacts (http://artifacts.ijk.company.se:8081/nexus/content/groups/public/): Illegal character in path at index 102: http://artifacts.ijk.company.se:8081/nexus/content/groups/public/com/company/ssb/cpm/common/pmcore/[0.1,)/pmcore-[0.1,).jar
  com.company.ssb.cpm.common:pmcore:jar:null

from the specified remote repositories:
  artifacts (http://artifacts.ijk.company.se:8081/nexus/content/groups/public/, releases=true, snapshots=true)

    at org.apache.maven.artifact.resolver.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:232)
    at org.apache.maven.artifact.resolver.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:164)
    at org.apache.maven.artifact.resolver.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:555)
    at org.apache.karaf.tooling.features.GenerateFeaturesFileMojo.isBundle(GenerateFeaturesFileMojo.java:407)
    at org.apache.karaf.tooling.features.GenerateFeaturesFileMojo.writeBundle(GenerateFeaturesFileMojo.java:300)
    at org.apache.karaf.tooling.features.GenerateFeaturesFileMojo.writeBundle(GenerateFeaturesFileMojo.java:292)
    at org.apache.karaf.tooling.features.GenerateFeaturesFileMojo.writeProjectDependencyFeatures(GenerateFeaturesFileMojo.java:256)
    at org.apache.karaf.tooling.features.GenerateFeaturesFileMojo.populateProperties(GenerateFeaturesFileMojo.java:197)
    at org.apache.karaf.tooling.features.GenerateFeaturesFileMojo.execute(GenerateFeaturesFileMojo.java:172)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:132)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:120)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:347)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:584)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:213)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:157)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: Could not transfer artifact com.company.ssb.cpm.common:pmcore:jar:[0.1,) from/to artifacts (http://artifacts.ijk.company.se:8081/nexus/content/groups/public/): Illegal character in path at index 102: http://artifacts.ijk.company.se:8081/nexus/content/groups/public/com/company/ssb/cpm/common/pmcore/[0.1,)/pmcore-[0.1,).jar
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:262)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:239)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveArtifact(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:295)
    at org.apache.maven.artifact.resolver.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:222)
    ... 29 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactTransferException: Could not transfer artifact com.company.ssb.cpm.common:pmcore:jar:[0.1,) from/to artifacts (http://artifacts.ijk.company.se:8081/nexus/content/groups/public/): Illegal character in path at index 102: http://artifacts.ijk.company.se:8081/nexus/content/groups/public/com/company/ssb/cpm/common/pmcore/[0.1,)/pmcore-[0.1,).jar
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector$6.wrap(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:1016)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector$6.wrap(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:1004)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector$GetTask.run(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:725)
    at org.eclipse.aether.util.concurrency.RunnableErrorForwarder$1.run(RunnableErrorForwarder.java:67)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in path at index 102: http://artifacts.ijk.company.se:8081/nexus/content/groups/public/com/company/ssb/cpm/common/pmcore/[0.1,)/pmcore-[0.1,).jar
    at java.net.URI.create(URI.java:859)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.client.methods.HttpGet.<init>(HttpGet.java:69)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.AbstractHttpClientWagon.fillInputData(AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:841)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.getInputStream(StreamWagon.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.getIfNewer(StreamWagon.java:88)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.get(StreamWagon.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector$GetTask.run(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:660)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in path at index 102: http://artifacts.ijk.company.se:8081/nexus/content/groups/public/com/company/ssb/cpm/common/pmcore/[0.1,)/pmcore-[0.1,).jar
    at java.net.URI$Parser.fail(URI.java:2829)
    at java.net.URI$Parser.checkChars(URI.java:3002)
    at java.net.URI$Parser.parseHierarchical(URI.java:3086)
    at java.net.URI$Parser.parse(URI.java:3034)
    at java.net.URI.<init>(URI.java:595)
    at java.net.URI.create(URI.java:857)
    ... 10 more
[ERROR]  unable to find suitable bundle for artifact 'com.company.ssb.cpm.common:pmcore:jar:[0.1,):compile'
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
```

Maven version is 3.2.2

There is a version 0.1.0 jar in the {user home}.m2\repository\com\company\ssb\pm\common\pmcore\0.1.0

My pom.xml is

```
    ...
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.company.ssb.nbda.pm</groupId>
        <artifactId>api</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.1</version>
    </dependency>
    ....



    ...
<plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.karaf.tooling</groupId>
                    <artifactId>features-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.3.5</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>generate-features-file</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>generate-features-file</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <karafVersion>2.3.5</karafVersion>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
           ...
```

The pom in com/company/ssb/nbda/pm/api/0.9.1/ is as follows:

```
...
  <groupId>com.company.ssb.nbda.pm</groupId>
  <artifactId>api</artifactId>
  <version>0.9.1</version>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.company.ssb.pm.common</groupId>
      <artifactId>pmcore</artifactId>
      <version>[0.1,)</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.company.ssb.cil.client</groupId>
      <artifactId>service</artifactId>
      <version>[0.10,)</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
 ...
```

Comment: Could you provide the whole output? And please reduce the pasted code to the relevant parts.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in response. I have now added the entire output and shortened the code to the relevant parts. Thanks!

Comment: Does it work if you specify the target revision directly without using ranges?

Comment: Yes it does. I changed the version to <version>0.10</version> in the pom of com/company/ssb/nbda/pm/api/0.9.1/ and it seems to work.

Comment: Sorry for the typo in the response above, <version>0.1.0</version>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its most likely a bug. I just dug into the code of Karaf and Maven, but couldn't find the correct place in the time frame I set myself for this, but some other interesting things, have a read:

I noticed that your Karaf 2.3.5 uses `maven 3.0. alpha 2`. So, most likely upgrading to Karaf 3.0.1 will help you but keep in mind that the commands for feature-maven-plugin have changed. If not, file a bug report with the data from this question here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KARAF

I took a look into the `GenerateFeaturesFileMojo.java`.

The method thats failing there (line 407) contains the code that searches the `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` for bundle informations.

This invokes the `DefaultArtifactResolver.java` (as you can also see in your stack trace) on a deprecated method, where the url is constructed through the `ArtifactRequest.java` (that you can't see in stack trace)

From there it continues into the maven code of resolving Artifacts, this is code that works well in Maven, so I assumed it would do so here, given that the Artifact information is correct.

So I started poking around the Karef code to figure out how the Artifact Objects are build in the first place but couldn't understand it easily, so I tried to figure out where the Artifacts were build and came across comments (and code) that said things like "@TODO: That works for now but it should be fixed" at places where the version came into the artifacts.

So, while this unfortunately is not a definite answer, your approach should work, if it doesn't its a bug.

Comment: Upgrading to karaf 3.0.1 works, by using the karaf maven plugin. So it seems to be a bug in the 2.3.5 branch. Thanks for the analysis!